# Referencing properties set in a build.xml in a filter task

Tags: ant, properties, filter, token

I understand that we can use the filter ant task to pick up tokens from a file such as in 
`<filter filtersfile="deploy_env.properties"/>`

I also know that you can do 
`<filter token="year" value="2000"/>`
 and set the value of token year to 2000 .

I don't want to change the build.xml. but I want to be use the value of certain property that have been set in the ant files as tokens.

How do I do this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use [echoproperties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoproperties.html) to save current properties to a file and then use that file for filtering.

Comment: I cant change the ant xml files. The motivation behind what i asked  is that the build system recurses down to some sub-dirs and does what it does. I want to be able to use the subdirectory name as a filter token to replace in a specific file in that subdirectory. The subdir is available as a property I was hoping to use that information directly... Is there some way to say in the token, use current directory as token value ?